# What is the Best method to query a mysql similar table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables table1, table2, table3

```
Table1
user ID,name, class, rollno, maths, English, literature
Table2 
User ID, name, class, rollno, maths, English, physics
Table3
User ID, name, class, rollno, maths, English, geography
```

What is the best way to query mysql to fetch one distinct result

```
$query = "select * from table1 where class='class and rollno='rollno'
Union
select * from table2 where class='class and rollno='rollno'
Union
select * from table3 where class='class and rollno='rollno' ";
```

It doesn't work when I do it this way

Comment: Your question is missing alot of infromation to answer it please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).. Pretend you are one off us and you're seeing the answer for the first time: does it make sense?

Comment: Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question then you will find out how impossible to answer on this.. As SQL is declarative where you define what you want not how to get it makes it not more easy ...  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The "best" method would be fix the design and avoid "similar" tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can understand by your question, You need to get all distinct rows from 3 or more tables with similar column names.

The best way to do so is by using **union**, As you are doing, But in union you need to specify column name also.

```
$query = "select User_ID, name, class, rollno, maths, English, physics from table1 where class='class and rollno='rollno'
Union
select User_ID, name, class, rollno, maths, English, physics from table2 where class='class and rollno='rollno'
Union
select User_ID, name, class, rollno, maths, English, physics from table3 where class='class and rollno='rollno' ";
```

This will help you out. and if you need all columns with duplicate entries then use **union all**.

Comment: Yes This is the best way

Comment: The tables are different so when I use mysql Union I get a mysqli_num_rows error

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand from your question how you want to build your result set, but generally speaking, there are two main ways to combine results in sql: join and union.

`join` means taking two datasets and connecting them in a way that each row in the results will contain columns from both datasets, and the results will be connected by some shared column.
In the table structure you described, it can be userId to combine the results, giving you a row with userId, geography (from table1) and physics (from table2)

`union` means taking two datasets and connecting them in a way that each row comes from one of the tables, and the results is simply all rows from table 1 + all rows from table 2 (with or without duplicates). The limitation here is that two datasets should contain the same columns.
For example in your tables it can be taking userId, name and maths from all three tables.